# Multiplying arrays of different dimentions without forloop

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays of different dimmentions. One has size A = (100000,9) the other has B= (15,100000). I want to multiply these arrays such that I get an array of size (135,100000) where each of the nine elements of A is multiplied by each of the 15 elements of B. Is there a way to do this without using a forloop?

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it for a couple of smaller matrices :-)

Couple of points to orient you as you read:

(1) my example relies on numpy, which has array slicing

(2) if `x` is a numpy array, `x[:,i]` means the `i`th column of x

(3) `itertools.product(items1, items2)` returns an iterable object over the cartesian product of the elements in `items1` and `items2`

(4) `numpy.stack(blah)` stacks the numpy arrays in blah, but has to be a tuple, not a list. Hence we convert the list comprehension in the line commented `[1]` to a tuple.

Then we have:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

x = np.array([
  [1,2],
  [2,3],
  [3,4],
  [5,6]
  ])
 
y = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [0,1,2]
    ])

cartesian = it.product(range(x.shape[1]), range(y.shape[1]))
all_cols = tuple([x[:,i] * y[:,j] for (i, j) in cartesian]) # [1]
print(np.stack(all_cols).T)
```

Output:

[image]